# Equivalent "AND NOT IN" regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python for reading a XML file and I need to find all **invalid** XML entities so I'm using regex `".*&[a-zA-Z0-9];.*"` but I don't want to match **valid** entities (`&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`) Can I do it with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
&(?!(?:quot|amp|apos|lt|gt);)[a-zA-Z0-9]*;
```